# Need help with my roblox animations movements

Tags: animation

So im trying to make my animation movements more smoother, and more natural, but my question is there an easier more simple way to do movements? ive been using the move arrows and rotation button. I,m using blender 2.8 if that is any help.

Comment: hello, you don't give enough informations, what movement are you talking about, in what way is not smooth, etc...

Comment: To make animations more smooth, you need to edit the interpolation between each keyframe with the graph editor..